# Internal 500 error on ajax post

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, jquery-ui

I am trying to post on our ajax a request to update a user meta (this is not wordpress related question). The way I do it is, I use the jquery draggable UI with .position to retrieve the position.top number, at stop() i called the function that posts the value to the ajax file. For some reason it returns 500 internal error and makes our ajax file inactive for all the other functions.

This is the first step
    
                
                    $(document).ready(function() {

```
                $(".top_image_roll").hide();

            $(".five img").draggable({
                axis: "y",
                // Find original position of dragged image.
                start: function(event, ui) {

                    // Show start dragged position of image.
                    var Startpos = $(this).position();
                },

                // Find position where image is dropped.
                stop: function(event, ui) {

                    // Show dropped position.
                    var Stoppos = $(this).position();
                    update_image_coords_1(Stoppos.top);

                }
            });
            });
            </script>
        <?php } else { ?>           
        <?php }?>
```

This is the function

```
function update_image_coords_1(coordss) {

  $.post('http://xxx/xxx/xxx/xxx/ajax.php',
    {
      'action': 'update_image_coords_1',
      'coords': coordss,
      'user_id': '<?php echo $user_id; ?>'

    }
  );
}
```

and this  is on ajax file

```
if( !empty($_REQUEST['action']) && $_REQUEST['action'] == 'update_image_coords_1' && !empty($_REQUEST['user_id']) && !empty($_REQUEST['coords'])) {

$coords = $_REQUEST['coords'];
update_user_meta($_REQUEST['user_id'], 'update_image_coords_1', $coords); 
die();
}
```

Is there something I am doing wrong? Any other suggestions? thanks in advance

Comment: Your PHP file has invalid syntax - the `if` statement doesn't have enough closing brackets. You need an extra one after each of the last two calls to `empty`, I believe.

Comment: Why are you using die() at the end? That may be the issue.

Comment: andrewsi.... I just noticed that.... I am checking

Comment: @JasonKaczmarsky 'die()' is required in wordpress ajax functions

Comment: I checked the closing brackets and they are correct.

Comment: everything looks a bit confused to me in your code , either you pasted it wrong here in SE , or you are totally mixing JS and PHP without regarding the proper syntax, brackets , or opening tags .. both ways (Js inside PHP and PHP inside JS ..

Comment: @NikolaosVassos - no. The PHP if statement you've included is not correct. It's missing two closing brackets.

Comment: The logic is pretty straight forward, first part takes the coords, second part is what is being sent to ajax, and then ajax function. I don't really mix anything. All syntax and brackets are in place.

Comment: It was missing 1 closing bracket, the last one for some reason went after the code part in stackoverflow. I fixed it but issue remained, 500 internal error

Comment: @NikolaosVassos - Could you add the new version to your question, please?

Comment: That was the culprit Andrew, How can i choose you for correct answer?

Comment: @NikolaosVassos - I've added it as an answer now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your if statement is missing a couple of closing brackets after the `empty` calls:

```
if( !empty( $_REQUEST['action']) && $_REQUEST['action'] == 'update_image_coords_1' && !empty($_REQUEST['user_id'] && !empty($_REQUEST['coords']) {
```

Should be:

```
if( !empty( $_REQUEST['action']) && $_REQUEST['action'] == 'update_image_coords_1' && !empty($_REQUEST['user_id']) && !empty($_REQUEST['coords'])) {
```

Comment: Thank you all the rest for input

Answer (score 2):

internal 500 probably means u have a syntax error/other fatal error in your PHP code.
As stated in comments, your `if` statement is in a mess of brackets.

What you should do, is **open the Apache error logs** and the problem will present itself VERY NICELY for you to fix.

Comment: it's a wordpress function Itay.

Comment: @Nikolaos Vassos I removed this a few seconds after posted, some times takes my cog wheels a few seconds to click into place